# Surjective sum measure

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of positive real numbers convergent to $0$. Let $\mu(A) = \sum_{n \in A}a_n$ for every $A \subset \mathbb{N}$. What is the "if and only if" condition on $a_n$ for $\mu$ to attain every value from $[0, \mu(\mathbb{N})]$?

Comment: As an illustration, $a_n=1/n$ or $a_n=1/2^n$ have the desired property, while $a_n=1/2.00000001^n$ doesn't.

Comment: I have posted an adapted version of this question on [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361343/is-there-a-known-condition-for-partial-sums-of-a-decreasing-positive-sequence-to), where I hope it will get more attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Will Brian and others on [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361343/is-there-a-known-condition-for-partial-sums-of-a-decreasing-positive-sequence-to), the question can be answered as follows.

First, reorder the sequence with the permutation $\sigma:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ defined recursively by $$\sigma(0):=\min\{i\in\Bbb N:a_i=\max\{a_j:j\in\Bbb N\},$$
$$\sigma(n+1):=\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$
$$\min\{i\in \Bbb N\setminus\{\sigma(0),...,\sigma(n)\}:a_i=\max\{a_j:j\in\Bbb N\setminus\{\sigma(0),...,\sigma(n)\}\}\}$$
$$(n\in\Bbb N),$$so that $(a_{\sigma(n)})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is the decreasing reordering of $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$. A necessary and sufficient condition for the required property of $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is then $$a_{\sigma(n)}\leqslant\sum_{m=n+1}^\infty a_{\sigma(m)}\quad(n\in\Bbb N).$$